# Remove double space after a period

Tags: posts, functions, visual-editor

I run a multiple author platform with more than 1000 writers. Most users writer their content externally (Microsoft Word, OpenOffice etc) and paste it into the Visual Editor. Around 20% of the articles have a double space after every single period.

Feedback from the users tells me that some versions of these programs adds two spaces after full stop instead of one. I initially linked these users to tutorials of how to address this in the external application itself however the growth of the platform is making this a ridiculously exhausting task.

**Is there a way to remove all double spaces and convert them into single space on the post page**? Maybe upon clicking publish. It would be ideal if it happened on the backend post page rather than the front end (through some styling fix) - although I am open to ideas.

On a personal note, I find it quite astonishing that this feature is not a part of the core functions of Wordpress given that at least 20% of my authors are experiencing it.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Multiple spaces are rendered as just one space in HTML. Nobody should ever see two spaces.

Comment: How come it is rendering two spaces on my platform? Can you kindly try to add two spaces in the **visual editor** and see how it displays?

Comment: @toscho Actually nevermind, I just ran a test on a fresh Wordpress install and it clearly adds two spaces, please check this example post: http://bogsorken.com/wpse/wordpress/?p=4

Comment: Ah, I see. TinyMCE turns the second space into a non-breaking space. This should be solved in JavaScript.

Comment: @toscho Would you know how to solve this in Javascript?

Comment: This worked perfectly for me in late 2021, even though it hasn't been updated for years: https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-double-space/

Answer (score 5):

I cannot offer a JavaScript solution, because I am not sure where exactly this is happening.

But … we can hook into `wp_insert_post_data` and solve this issue in PHP:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 't5_strip_double_spaces', 20 );

function t5_strip_double_spaces( $data )
{
    $data['post_content'] = preg_replace(
        "~( \x{C2}\x{A0}|\x{C2}\x{A0} )~m",
        ' ',
        $data['post_content']
    );
    return $data;
}
```

As [plugin on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/4228493).

Comment: I'll dig more later when I have time, but there might be a [`tiny_mce_init` filter configuration](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration) that could work here, too.

Comment: No, this will catch only occurrences of `space+no-break-space`, not regular double space.

Comment: Excellent - will I need to update each published post for this to have effect?

Comment: @ChipBennett If you have the time to find a `tiny_mce_init` filter, I would be grateful.

Comment: You could send this function over all existing posts too. On the other hand, this should be possible in plain SQL.

Comment: @toscho I just tested your code and it does not function correctly. This is very odd. At first test, it removed the double space after period, at second try, it did not. I made the test on this post: http://bogsorken.com/wpse/wordpress/?p=4 I have updated the post several times without any effect. Also of consideration, will this remove double space after `:`, `?` and `!`? Any ideas?

Comment: @AmandaDuke Try my updated code. I have no time for this currently. The editor seems to inject `no-break-space+space` sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `functions.php` file

```
<?php

function my_the_content_filter ($content)
{
    str_replace('.  ', '. ', $content);

    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content, 'my_the_content_filter');
```

That *should* do the trick. Hope it helps!

[Codex Page for Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content)

Comment: Interesting approach. Would this not interfere with any form of code that uses double space within it? I cannot think of any form of code in the content that would use double space on top of my head but the possibility exists, right? For instance, an image URL that has contains a double space...

Comment: URLs shouldn't have a double space in the first place, but I did think about that possibility. In my edit, I added '.  ' to target ONLY the double spaces that come after a full stop.

Comment: I just tested this code and it gave me a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING` error. Do you know what the issue is? Also, can you make it so that it detects double spaces after `:` and `!` and `?`

Comment: Awwww. I was typing fast and made a silly little typo. Change the line `add_filter('the_content, 'my_the_content_filter');` to `add_filter('the_content', 'my_the_content_filter');` I have problems with quotes sometimes.